# SBT/Scala: macro implementation not found

Tags: scala, macros, sbt

I tried my hand on macros, and I keep running into the error

> macro implementation not found: W
>   [error] (the most common reason for that is that you cannot use macro implementations in the same compilation run that defines them)

I *believe* I've set up a two pass compilation with the macro implementation being compiled first, and the usage second.

Here is part of the /build.sbt:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(rootSettings: _*).
  settings(name := "Example").
  aggregate(macros, core).
  dependsOn(macros, core)

lazy val macros = (project in file("src/main/com/example/macros")).
  settings(macrosSettings: _*).
  settings(name := "Macros")

lazy val core = (project in file("src/main/com/example/core")).
  settings(coreSettings: _*).
  settings (name := "Core").
  dependsOn(macros)


lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := Organization,
  version := Version,
  scalaVersion := ScalaVersion
)

lazy val rootSettings = commonSettings ++ Seq(
  libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps ++ rootDeps ++ macrosDeps ++ coreDeps
)

lazy val macrosSettings = commonSettings ++ Seq(
  libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps ++ macrosDeps
)

lazy val coreSettings = commonSettings ++ Seq(
  libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps ++ coreDeps
)
```

The macro implementation looks like this:

/src/main/com/example/macros/Macros.scala

```
object Macros {
  object Color {
    def ColorWhite(c: Context): c.Expr[ObjectColor] = c.Expr[ObjectColor](c.universe.reify(ObjectColor(White())).tree)
  }
}
```

The usage looks like this:

/src/main/com/example/core/Main.scala

```
object Macros {
  import com.example.macros.Macros._
  def W: ObjectColor = macro Color.ColorWhite
}

object Main extends App {
  import Macros._
  println(W)
}
```

Scala 2.11.6. SBT 0.13.8.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your advice!

**Fawlty Project:**

[The Project on Github](https://github.com/Wonkoson/playground/tree/b74f5f64eee5cb95b2ea84545ee93ba4d8c2b4ca)

**Working Project:**

Rearranged the projects to a more correct form:

[The cleanedup working project](https://github.com/Wonkoson/playground/tree/d584598bffd6294f860ac6708cb1253b3f3f33ad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `macros` and `core` projects don't contain any files, so they don't cause the problem. The error happens when sbt compiles `root`, which contains both Main.scala and Macros.scala by the virtue of you saying `project in file(".")` in the sbt build.

Comment: Hi Eugene! And as I understand i should partition code with macros and code without macros into two separate sbt projects? Right? And assume I have a class Foo to instantiate, a class Bar who want to instantiate it and module object Macro with newInstance method. So i should make common project with Foo, and 2 projets for bar and macro which are depending on common right?